# Firebase document deletion odd number of segments

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete an entry from firebase upon clicking a button in my table, but i get this error :

> FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must > have an even number of segments, but iEwblJo832nnC6TkFDEy has 1.

I don't understand why the document has an odd number of segments since I just queried it. How can i fix this ?

The function which does the query select and attempts deletion

```
async deleteMovie(movieToDelete : Movie) {
    await this.moviesRef.ref.where('includedBy', '==', movieToDelete.includedBy).where('title', '==', movieToDelete.title).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => this.database.doc(doc.id).delete());
    });
    return true;
  }
```

The click function of the delete button

```
async deleteEntry (item : Movie) {
    let idx = this.movieData.data.indexOf(item);
    if(await this.movieService.deleteMovie(this.movieData.data[idx]) === true) {
      this.movieData.data.splice(idx,1);
      this.movieData._updateChangeSubscription();
    }
    else {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

The html page where the button is created

```
<div class="container-page">
    <p id="toolbar-top">
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
            Welcome (de pus numele userului aici)
            <button mat-icon-button id="logout-icon">
                <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon> Logout
            </button>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </p>
    <table class="mat-elevation-z8 table-main" mat-table [dataSource]="movieData" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Title </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="genre">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Genre </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.genre}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="watchStatus">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.watchStatus}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="rating">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Rating </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rating}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="wouldRecommend">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Recommended ? </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.wouldRecommend}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef ></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
              <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteEntry(row)">Delete</button> 
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator class="paginator-main" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]"
                 showFirstLastButtons 
                 aria-label="Select page of movies list">
    </mat-paginator>

    <button id="new-entry-button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addNewEntry()">Add new movie</button>
</div>
```

The movie interface

```
export interface Movie {
    includedBy : string;
    title : string;
    genre : string;
    watchStatus : string;
    rating : string;
    wouldRecommend : string;
}
```

This is how my firebase collection looks like
[image: how my firebase collection looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying `this.moviesRef`, but then are deleting from `this.database`, so it seems those two references are different.

To delete from a query, you can just get the reference of the document snapshot in the result itself:

```
this.moviesRef.ref
  .where('includedBy', '==', movieToDelete.includedBy)
  .where('title', '==', movieToDelete.title)
  .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.ref.delete());
  });
```